# How do i prove that Mobius transformation is continuous at its pole?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $a,b,c,d$ be complex numbers such that $c\neq 0$ and $ad-bc\neq 0$.

Define $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}, \forall z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{-\dfrac{d}{c}\right\}$.

Define $T(-\frac{d}{c})=\infty$ and $T(\infty)=\frac{a}{b}$.

This function $T:\overline{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ is called a Mobius transformation.

I have proved that $T$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-\frac{d}{c}\}$.

How do i prove that $\lim_{z\to -\frac{d}{c}} T(z) = \infty$?

Comment: Did you also prove $T$ is continuous at $\infty$?  It would seem arhythmic to omit that from this exercise. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work if $a/b=c/d$ for reasons you can figure out.

Suppose you prove $az+b$ approaches some number in $\mathbb C$ other than $0$ as $z\to-d/c$.

*Then* the problem is to prove that $1/(cz+d)\to\infty$ as $z\to-d/c$.

$$
\frac{1}{cz+d} = \frac 1 c \cdot \frac{1}{z+\frac d c}. \tag 1
$$

(Maybe you can also think about what happens if $c=0$, since $c$ is in two denominators here.)

Given $R>0$, you need find $\delta>0$ such that the second fraction on the right in $(1)$ is bigger than $R$ if $|z-\frac d c |<\delta$.  Maybe $\delta=1/R$ works.